# Creating an interface or type for a Map

Tags: typescript

I would like to have a single type or interface for a JavaScript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Given the base code :

```
const things = new Map();
```

I currently create one type and one interface to explicitly type the `things` variable and the `Map` constructor call.

```
type Things = Map<string, ThingValue>;

interface ThingValue {
  label: string;
  count: number;
}


const things: Things = new Map<string, ThingValue>();
```

I would like to have a single type or interface so that I don't have to repeat `<string, ThingValue>`.

Is this possible?
Alternatively, what are the best practices for typing JavaScript `Map`s?

Comment: You don't need the `Things` type if you just do `const things = new Map<string, ThingValue>();`

Comment: @iz_ But then if I need to type a similar object I will have to repeat `<string, ThingValue>`  every time, which is error prone. I'm hoping there's a cleaner way (maybe there isn't).

Comment: You can either define it like `const things: Things = new Map();` or `const things = new Map<string, ThingValue>();`. In both cases, you have the absolute minimum information needed to convey the type.

Comment: @iz_ I agree. This may be irrational but I don't like seeing `var Map: MapConstructor
new () => Map<any, any>` when i hover over `new Map()`;

Comment: It won't make a lot of practical sense, but I guess you could also go the route of `function mapFactory() {
return new Map<string, ThingValue>();
}` if you really wanted to.

Comment: @iz_  that would be even worse. Not saying that what I want is possible or even the right way, I'm just bothered by this little detail.

Comment: @Sébastien Then, assuming you're going to create multiple, I would go with `const things: Things = new Map();`. I don't think you can really get better than that.

Comment: @iz_ Thanks for your replies. If you leave an answer I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 3 options to correctly type the map without redundancy:

```
type Things = Map<string, ThingValue>;

interface ThingValue {
  label: string;
  count: number;
}

const things1: Things = new Map();
const things2 = new Map<string, ThingValue>();

// not recommended
const mapFactory = () => new Map<string, ThingValue>();
const things3 = mapFactory();
```

All will result in the same type and contain the minimum information needed to convey the type.